# Ruby to C# expression

Tags: c#, ruby

how to convert to C#, the following Ruby expression:

```
  @fields.map(&:bit_size).reduce(&:+)
```

Comment: explain it properly, like how that statement works with example..

Comment: and this is an example of the xml file

<struct><id>28</id><name>MCC Header</name><fields><field><format>0</format<id>121</id><name>field</name><unit-bit-size>2048</unit-bit-size></field></fields></struct>

Comment: @H.Mahida I don't know C#, but that Ruby code adds up the result of calling `.bit_size` on each element of the array `@fields`.

Comment: Yes what you are saying is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` is called `Select` in .NET, and `reduce` is called `Aggregate`. You can just translate it literally:

```
fields.Select(field => field.bitSize).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jorg, You're the Man

Comment: Hello Jrog, please i need help with converting a ruby expression to c# expression, this is the expression;

    xml.elements.each('fields/field') do |field_xml|


xml is an xml file that look like this:

<fields>
    <field>
        <format>3</format>
        <id>136</id>
        <name>Filler</name>
        <unit-bit-size>15</unit-bit-size>
    </field>
<fields>